# What happens if a Confessor tries to Confess an already Confessed person?

Tags: magic, mind-control, the-sword-of-truth

This is in relation to both the Sword of Truth and the Legend of the Seeker universes. I have only seen the tv-series, but I'm interested in an answer drawing from the books canon.

The question is really simple, as stated in the title: What happens if a Confessor tries to Confess an already Confessed person?

Logically, there are two possibilities: (1) nothing happens, (2) the previous Confession is reversed in favor of the new one. Of course, something else like (3) the person dies / becomes mad, can happen as well, but it's just guesswork.

I do not remember any such attempts made in the LotS, mainly because seldom we had more than one Confessor in the scene.

On the other hand, at least in one instance, it would have been really useful, namely when Richard was Confessed by a young girl (the episode "Touched") and Kahlan's immediate reaction was to try and kill her.

Comment: Their head explodes and it makes a real mess.

Comment: I wish I knew if I should take this seriously

Comment: There was only one confessor for the entirety of the book series too.  My unfounded guess is that 1 is unlikely, and 2 or 3 (looney tunes) is likely.  I am not familiar with the TV show though, and your latest edit makes me figure they changed a bunch of stuff.

Comment: @YuriyS - "*Kahlan looked down again at the only man she had ever loved. Still wearing her Confessor face, she cupped a hand to Richard’s cold cheek. Even though his flesh was cold, the magic kept it as soft as it had been in life. And then his head exploded. Kabooom! "Ooh. That'll take a while to clean up" said Kahlan "I'll need some Dettol and a roll of kitchen towel*" - Sword of Truth: Warheart

Comment: @Valorum - I'd honestly forgotten the series kept going, and then you had to make me google that.  Damnit.

Answer (score 7):

## No canon answer.

From the books, we can learn that:

- A Confessor's touch removes something of a person's self. As the magic takes it away (to the Underworld), the person touched is an empty shell, totally devoted to the Confessor in a form of unconditional love<sup>*</sup>.
- A Confessor's touch does not go away when she dies, a person touched may not survive such a loss<sup>*</sup>.
- Effects of the touch are diminished when the subject is transformed into an animal by a Wizard<sup>**</sup>.

*Kahlan's father, a mate to her mother, the previous Mother Confessor, was so devoted to her, that he died on the spot when he found out that she was terminally ill.

**<sub>The Stone Of Tears, Chapter 11</sub>**

> “My father was mate to a Confessor. That was all that was in him. When my mother was
>   dying of a terrible wasting illness, he was in a constant state of panic. One day the wizard
>   and the healer who had been tending her came to us and said there was nothing more they
>   could do, that the spirits would soon take her to be with them, that she would soon pass
>   from life.”
>
> “With a wail of anguish like none I have ever heard, my father clutched his chest and fell to
>   the floor, dead.”

This is contradicted by the TV series, where death of a Confessor releases their victim.

** *Brophy*, a suspect to murder found innocent by Kahlan, is still following her, after being transformed into a wolf by Giller, Kahlan's acccompanying Wizard. However, he lives a normal wolf life.

**<sub>Wizards First Rule, Chapter 38</sub>**

> [Brophy:] “Mistress, when I was changed to the wolf, it removed most of my need for you, my need to please you. Yet I would still die for you.

Knowing that, we can deduce that a person already confessed has nothing for the second confessor to take away. It is possible that the second touch will either kill them, or drive them mad. However, it may cause no effect:

At the end of Wizard's First Rule,

> Richard, being ultimately devoted to Kahlan through love, survived her touch intact.

---

*UPD:* Another consideration is that a second confessor has no point of confessing that person. As all Confessors belong to the same group, led by The Mother Confessor, they all pursue the same goal. If one Confessor has touched a person, she has probably solved the case and proved that he/she is guilty (typically such a person dies on the spot after confession) or innocent (then he/she is turned into an animal of choice by the Confessor's accompanying Wizard). If a Confessor uses her power on a person for self-defense, and decides to keep them alive, she would keep them close (eg. to protect her, like Kahlan used Orsk) - the person confessed will be eager to do so, unless she sends them on some suicide mission (Kahlan sent captured Order troops back to try to assasinate Jagang). Finally, a Confessor touches a man to be her mate, to bear a daughter Confessor.

**Conclusion:** a Confessor is unlikely to meet a person already touched by another Confessor (at least without that Confessor nearby), and is unlikely to have a reason to confess that person again.

Comment: Thank you. I should probably try reading the books. I'll accept the answer soon

Answer (score 2):

I havent read the books, sorry, but at least in the TV show, when Richard was confessed to Annabelle, she was going to have him sleep with Kahlan to make another Confessor, without Kahlan Confessing him, which says, in that context at least, nothing would happen. They didn't mention any other consequences.

Comment: That's a good point

Comment: The TV series has the whole Confessor concept messed up. As well as other things.

Comment: It's been a while since I read the books, but I seem to recall that the reason Richard wasn't affected by Kahlan's touch is that is that he already loved her totally, so there was nothing for the confessing power to do. Thus I think this is the correct answer from the book's perspective as well: nothing would happen.